# Access SQL How to select randomly a group of contiguous rows

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ado

can this be done, say I have rows (1,2,3,4,5) and I want to grab three rows, select one randomly and then get it's neighbors, so maybe the random selection is row (3), I can also grab (2,4) if I wanted its neighbors, do I just pick one at random and then look for the unique key before and after like this or can I do it all in one sql statement.

I was going to use ADO from excel to pull records (so VBA connects to access, opens a recordset with sql instructions and so on).

Hope I was clear!

I would love to just do this all in a SQL statement

Comment: If only `SQL` was more tuned to random needs...

Comment: Depends on how you're numbering your rows.  Theorhetically, if I understand correctly, you can just use a BETWEEN statement in your WHERE clause.

Comment: If you select 1 or 5, who are the neighbors?

Comment: looks like I'll randomly generate a number and use between to grab how many rows I want to select it's contiguous members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure Access is capable of all the SQL commands such as SQL Server, so this may be a bit of a problem. If you have a primary key though, you can easly generate a Select query in VBA and then pass open recordset with this SQL.

```
Dim sSQL as String
Dim lRand as Long
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset 'or DAO.Recordset'
lRand = VBA.Int(VBA.Rnd() * TableRecordCount) ' TableRecordCount is the number of records in the table that you need to get somehow'
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (ID>=" & lRand - 1 & " AND ID <=" & lRand + 1
set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL, ...)
```

I am now not absolutely sure of what you want to use and depending on ADODB or DAO choice, you need to open the recordset accordingly with wither `Call rs.Open` or `Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset`

Comment: This is perfect, I am using ADODB but the idea is all I needed, I have  primary keys so I will just select contiguous